# Cannot List by several Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have 1 projects table for all projects as well and 1 ProjectsManager table for managers.So I am trying to get logged member Id and find him/her in manager table and then list projects which he/she is managing. here is the code ;

this code for finding logged member in manager table;

```
 var ProjectManagerForProject = Db.MyManagers.Where(o => o.ProjectManagerID.Equals(LoggedMember.Id)).Select(o=>o.Project.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

and the code for creating the list for logged member ;

```
  var model = new ProjectsModel
        {


            ItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage,
            Page = S,
            TotalItems = Db.MyProjects.Count(),
            OurProjects = Db.MyProjects.OrderBy(o => o.Sira).Where(o=>o.Id.Equals(ProjectManagerForProject)).Skip((S - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage)
            .Select(s => new ProjectsModel.TheProjects
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                ProjectName = s.ProjectName,
                PhaseCount = (short)Db.MyPhases.Where(p => p.Project.Id == s.Id).Count(),
                ProjectOwner=s.ProjectOwner,
                Priority=(PriorityForProject)s.Priority,
                StartDate=s.StartDate,
                EndDate=s.EndDate,
            })
        };
```

if I do this I get 1 Project Id and list 1 project but manager has several projects. I try to get as list with `toList();` end of the `ProjectManagerForProject`

But then I get null and this error ; `Cannot compare elements of type System.Collections.Generic.List1. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.`

How can I get several Id and list it ?

I have changed the code little bit so I can get several ID ;

```
var ProjectManagerForProject = Db.MyManagers.OrderBy(o=>o.Id).Where(o => o.ProjectManagerID.Equals(MevcutUye.Id)).Select(o=>o.Project.Id).ToList();
```

but cannot list still same error but for this ;

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.OurProjects)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this line of your code, if ProjectManagerForProject is a List of Ids:

```
.Where(o=>o.Id.Equals(ProjectManagerForProject))
```

instead do the following

```
.Where(o => ProjectManagerForProject.Contains(o.Id))
```

Comment: yes I was trying to use contains but couldnt figure it out how. Thanks a lot